# What do we do about mirror sites?

Tags: discussion

Following searching various things for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592442/is-it-legal-to-use-ubuntu-name-for-my-cybercaf%C3%A9/592454#592454), I found:

http://askubuntu.greatknow.com/questions/294850/does-canonical-have-other-deals-with-companies-like-the-amazon-search-feature

which seems like a mirror copy of:

[Does Canonical have other deals with companies like the Amazon search feature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294850/does-canonical-have-other-deals-with-companies-like-the-amazon-search-feature)

Now this makes me thing of 4 things:

- Is this site here to do harm? (e.g. a SE user signs in through it and gets their account nicked)
- Isn't there copyright infringement stuff that might cause issue?
- Is it affiliated with Ubuntu / Stack Exchange anyway?
- Any advertising making money from our content?

I have in the past found various weird sites that contain shortened versions of Stack Exchange questions/answers and link to the main post (e.g. [this site](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=997981)), this is the first that seems to be trying to copy it exactly..

---

At the bottom it links to http://photoemblem.greatknow.com/ http://pasteubuntu.greatknow.com/

http://www.greatknow.com/ appears to be some weird Q&A site.

It also updates to keep up-to-date with the current site. Compare http://askubuntu.greatknow.com/questions & https://askubuntu.com/questions, then panic.

Comment: Looking into this...

Comment: Man, that is so realistic it's scary! This is no ordinary scraper.

Comment: Wow. Yeah, that's scary.

Comment: Most of the CSS and stuff couldn't be ripped off, only the text, it seems.

Comment: OpenID is the only way to log in.

Comment: @therewillbecoffee - there is enough for it to be a effective copy. I haven't tried looking at the login as I assume that would not be a very good idea...

Comment: @Shog9 It also appears to reflect new content within about 5-10 seconds of new content being posted here.

Comment: @JasonC - wow didn;t notice that (will add to question) - it must being using the StackExchange APIs

Comment: Looks like [the SE team was victorious](http://i.snag.gy/22ILX.jpg).

Comment: @JasonC nice :D. I will add ubuntu's pastebin isn't.... http://pasteubuntu.greatknow.com/

Comment: Photoemblem is not theirs either, I've notified photoemblem's staff through their real site. At a glance, everything on that site is either spam or scraped content.

Comment: @JasonC - looks like it. I have used the contact form [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy) to notify canonical as well.

Comment: I call shenanigans. When I access this site I get the message `The owner of this website (askubuntu.com) has banned your IP address` but the ip address it states clearly isn't my ip address.

Comment: @MichaelLindman indeed. The IP is just written in the HTML (i.e doesn't change with each visitor) 

<p>
The owner of this website (askubuntu.com) has banned your IP address (104.156.49.140).
</p>

Comment: @MichaelLindman it probably is talking about blocking greatknow's server's IP not yours (otherwise u won't be able to use this site) *captain jamie* could still be changed fro each visitor - never mind :)

Comment: @Wilf Maybe but I've also noticed that the servers ip address is different from the "banned" one.

Comment: @MichaelLindman - might my a mirror or soemthing , dunno (i know some stuff about this, not everything)  ([89.248.171.173](https://freegeoip.net/?q=askubuntu.greatknow.com) shows as being in the netherlands, whilst https://freegeoip.net/?q=104.156.49.140 shows as in the US). I have also noticed http://mediafire.greatknow.com/ has been added to the bottom so perhaps they are trying something else (probably MUCH more evil).... https://www.mediafire.com/policy_violation/trademark.php ?

Comment: @Wilf I can't help but think that this attempt at deception can't possibly to aimed at the average AU user as I believe most of us are knowledgeable enough to see through it. This leads me to think that the possible target would be new users to Ubuntu who've never used AU or StackExchange before.

Comment: its probably aimed at poor sod who don't how a nasty and evil some people can be with computers... its probably not aimed as quite alot of 'us' lot cos we a) mainly use ubuntu linux, a target but not as big n easy as windowz with virus whatevers b) if find this sort of rubbish might do something about getting rid of it. I think quite few sites that scrape SE and other forums (the ones that link and do credit answers, not like this one) are doing it for the ad money, though they can slightly help increase the circulation of our questions and answers.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6gh1i4 -- Even my antimalware on Windows hates it.

Comment: @MichaelLindman That's a fake Cloudflare message.

Comment: I just had a reply from Canonical with `Thank you for getting in touch. We really appreciate you taking the time to report the following matter to us.`. At the bottom of the askubuntu greatknow page http://registryhubdocker.greatknow.com/  has been added which is a copy of https://registry.hub.docker.com/ - this may also need to be reported (via https://www.docker.com/company/contact/ ?). It has the Ubuntu logo as well so could be done for copyrighty stuff AGAIN.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*If you open your browser in privacy mode that site will start to open tabs and do all sorts of ads.*

#### For Ubuntu you can report things like that here:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

#### Here are instructions for reporting scrapers to SE:

- [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/203389)

Comment: Alright I will report as detailed on meta SCRAPER reporting page (both via contact form (thought from the comments it might be known about anyway)). By the way I found it by googling `stackexchange deal canonical ubuntu` (link [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackexchange+deal+canonical+ubuntu&btnG=Search&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr), for me it was the 6th result).

Comment: We're going to give this a little extra 'special' attention because it's just outright egregious.

Comment: Just to confirm, we asked our lawyers to have everyone associated with that awful thing fed to the sarlaac and THEN frozen in carbonite, to serve as a warning to others. (They've got to find 'em first, but you should know the wheels are in motion.)

Comment: ...and just for good measure, we took some actions on the technical side, too.  (try the link to see em.)

Comment: @Jaydles - works here - well done!

Comment: @Jaydles http://askubuntu.com.80bola.com/ ?

Comment: @bain Report that site as described above. I did not see how the site looked that is described in the original Question, but this one is really identical looking to our one.

Comment: @Jaydles Don't want to play the devil's advocate here, but the only things they are doing wrong are: a) not linking to the original source, b) using trademarks without permission. They could get around that and pop up as a different, comparable site. This really, really is an issue for new users.

Comment: @don.joey, the original link from the post ("greatknow") is a LOT worse than that.  They're using content created by folks like you to trick users clicking links into installing all kinds of crapware. We respond to trademark issues to protect them, but straight up proxies don't bother us much philosophically, as long as users aren't tricked or taken advantage of.  Those guys are doing bad stuff.

Comment: @bain Jesus, that site is dangerous, it managed to replace most of my awesomebar default favorites after visiting a few of the fake "network" links on that site.  We should all report that one!