# Found askubuntu copycat site, where do i report?

Tags: support

Here's the link:

http://askubuntu.com.80bola.com/questions/121373/etc-lightdm-unity-greeter-conf-file-missing

Been googling around for lightdm background image solutions, and found this. On google it looked normal, but once opened in new tab, noticed the weird url

Comment: A similar topic on Meta can be found [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13646/are-mirror-sites-allowed-or-a-issue-that-should-be-looked-at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can report scrapers here:  [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

I'm not entirely sure this counts as a scraper, per the conversation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250916/what-is-stackoverflow-com-80bola-com/251951#251951), although it is annoying.

Comment: Thank you. I submitted the url and searched string. I'm less annoyed and more worried that through such websites, users could have their personal information stolen