# What is this "clone" site doing? And why?

Tags: discussion

In a google search, I stumbled upon this site:

http://askubuntu.com.80bola.com/

Which seems to clone the askubuntu.com site. Apart the fact that I do not know if this is legal --- surely not really fair, I'm quite puzzled on "why" they're doing it. I do not see any spurious ad or similar in that pages...

Comment: Related: [http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13646/are-mirror-sites-allowed-or-a-issue-that-should-be-looked-at](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13646/are-mirror-sites-allowed-or-a-issue-that-should-be-looked-at)

Answer (score 2):

After checking what 80bola proper, it looks like a sports-betting and ad driven sort of website.  Probably saw that AU got pretty good rankings and either cloned or simply proxied the site.  Still, I think it tries to dodge the attribution rules and subvert the rules [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)